# Show div only if parent div height is smaller than the viewport height with CSS only

Tags: css, positioning, css-position

what I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
<body>
   <div id="content" style="position:relative;">
      ...some content here...
      THE END
      <div class="red_square" style="position:absolute;right:0;bottom:-90px;height:90px;width:90px;background-color:red;"></div>
   </div>
</body>
```

but that obviously just shows the red square at bottom. What I want is the page to stop at "THE END" if it's long enough (that is, whith scroll bars), and show the red div only for pages with little content (without scroll bars). I can do it with javascript but I was wondering if there is a pure CSS (2 or 3) solution for the most recent browsers.

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo of the functionality you want with JavaScript?

Comment: I think he only wants to show the red `div` if displaying it would not cause the vertical scroll bar to appear, if the scroll bar was not already there because of the height of the content. Maybe some kind of `@media` height query would work for this? Or just an `overflow: hidden` and `height: 100%` on something. Want confirmation on what he wants exactly before I start thinking about it too hard, though.

Comment: I guess u r referring to CSS expressions through which they can be done..u can search online for more info on that...but they have almost no support on IE...so be aware of that...

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if i get what your trying, perdon if in wrong.
There is max-height and min-height in the recent browsers, thats prolly help you